# libvirt: From state integer to string?

Tags: python, libvirt

I have this simple script to check the memory usage of virtual machines managed by libvirt.

How can I convert the integer for `state` from `dom.info()` to a human readable string?

```
import libvirt
import re

import sys


def mem_total_kb():
    meminfo = open('/proc/meminfo').read()
    matched = re.search(r'^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)', meminfo)
    return int(matched.groups()[0])


def main():
    conn = libvirt.openReadOnly(None)

    if conn == None:
        print 'Failed to open connection to the hypervisor'
        sys.exit(1)
    used_mem_sum = 0
    for domain_id in conn.listDomainsID():
        dom = conn.lookupByID(domain_id)
        state, max_mem, used_mem, vcpus, cpu_time_used = dom.info()
        print(
        'name=%s state=%s max_mem=%s used_mem=%s vcpus=%s cpu_time_used=%s' % (dom.name(), state, max_mem, used_mem, vcpus, cpu_time_used))
        used_mem_sum += used_mem
    print('Sum of used mem: %s KiB' % used_mem_sum)
    mem_total = mem_total_kb()
    print('Sum of physical mem: %s KiB' % mem_total)
    if used_mem_sum > mem_total:
        print('########## VMs use more RAM than available!')
        return
    mem_left=mem_total - used_mem_sum
    print('Memory left: %s KiB' % (mem_left))
    mem_left_should=4000000
    if mem_left<mem_left_should:
        print('less than mem_left_should=%sKiB left!' % mem_left_should)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Docs: https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainInfo

> state: the running state, one of virDomainState

```
enum virDomainState {

VIR_DOMAIN_NOSTATE  =   0   
no state
VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING  =   1   
the domain is running
VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCKED  =   2   
the domain is blocked on resource
VIR_DOMAIN_PAUSED   =   3   
the domain is paused by user
VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTDOWN =   4   
the domain is being shut down
VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTOFF  =   5   
the domain is shut off
VIR_DOMAIN_CRASHED  =   6   
the domain is crashed
VIR_DOMAIN_PMSUSPENDED  =   7   
the domain is suspended by guest power management
VIR_DOMAIN_LAST =   8   
NB: this enum value will increase over time as new events are added to the libvirt API. It reflects the last state supported by this version of the libvirt API.

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean, e.g. `1 -> One`?

Comment: @jcfollower I updated the question.

Comment: Since it's small, can you just build your own dictionary ...
`state_descr = {0: 'No State', 1: 'The domain is running', ... }`

Comment: @jcfollower yes, this would work. But I guess a better solution exists. With "better" I mean a solution where I can't do typos, where the names come from libvirt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like at least the enum constant names are exposed in the `libvirt` module. The following works for me...

```
import libvirt
import pprint
import re

d = {}
for k, v in libvirt.__dict__.iteritems():
    if re.match('VIR_DOMAIN_[A-Z]+$', k):
        d[v] = k

pprint.pprint(d)
```

...and prints...

```
{0: 'VIR_DOMAIN_NOSTATE',
 1: 'VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING',
 2: 'VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCKED',
 3: 'VIR_DOMAIN_PAUSED',
 4: 'VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTDOWN',
 5: 'VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTOFF',
 6: 'VIR_DOMAIN_CRASHED',
 7: 'VIR_DOMAIN_PMSUSPENDED'}
```

The descriptions, which are likely just comments in the original source code, are probably not exposed. One of the examples defines its own dictionary on [line 106](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/blob/master/examples/esxlist.py#L106)...

```
state_names = { libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING  : "running",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCKED  : "idle",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_PAUSED   : "paused",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTDOWN : "in shutdown",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTOFF  : "shut off",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_CRASHED  : "crashed",
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_NOSTATE  : "no state" }
```

...so you could just take it from there, although it seems to be incomplete.

Comment: The mapping from integers to VIR_DOMAIN_* names is all I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This bash script will fetch the list of `virDomainState` values (excluding `VIR_DOMAIN_LAST`) and their descriptions in JSON format:

```
#!/bin/bash

HEADER=include/libvirt/libvirt-domain.h

get_header_file()
{
    curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libvirt/libvirt/master/"$HEADER"
}

select_virDomainState_block()
{
    sed -n '/virDomainState:/,/^\} virDomainState;/ p'
}

join_multiline_comments()
{
    sed -n '\%/\*[^*]*$% N; \%/\*.*\*/$% { s/\s*\n\s*/ /; p; }'
}

enum_values_to_json_map()
{
    echo '{'
    sed "s/\s*VIR_DOMAIN\S\+\s*=\s*//; s^,\s*/\*\s*^ : '^; s^\s*\*/^',^;"
    echo '}'
}

get_header_file                 \
| select_virDomainState_block   \
| join_multiline_comments       \
| grep 'VIR_DOMAIN\S\+\s*='     \
| enum_values_to_json_map
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./get_libvirt_domain_states
{
0 : 'no state',
1 : 'the domain is running',
2 : 'the domain is blocked on resource',
3 : 'the domain is paused by user',
4 : 'the domain is being shut down',
5 : 'the domain is shut off',
6 : 'the domain is crashed',
7 : 'the domain is suspended by guest power management',
}
```

Note that the script downloads a ~150KB file from the libvirt mirror repository at GitHub. It is intended for facilitating staying up-to-date with the libvirt code. Of course you can call it from your python code, but personally I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Hmm this depends on internet connection.... is there no way to get from integer to string via libvirt?

Comment: libvirt doesn't seem to provide such functionality. At least I couldn't find it. You must maintain your own dictionary in the code (as @jcfollower proposed). I simply make it easier for you maintaining that dictionary in sync with the libvirt code.